# Не возможно найти класс из другого проекта. Или как же все таки правильно задать classpath

Tags: java, classpath

Прочитал про classpath в книге, не совсем понял что это, потом пошел гуглить, нашел две хорошие статьи. Прочитал их, вроде бы разорбался но суть в том что когда сам начал пробывать то все пошло не по плану. В чем суть, когда я разделяю проект на две части, тоесть в одной корневой дериктории скажем она называется **projectExample1** у нас есть под директория под название **src** в ней есть пакет (под директория) **first** и там лежит класс **Example1.java**. Далее я создал файл в нашей корневой дериктории **projectExample1** под названием **projectExample2** в ней есть лишь под директория **classes** с пакетом (под директориией) **second** в ктором уже скомпилированый **Example2.class**. Буду ОЧЕНЬ блогодарен тому кто даст ответ и сможет помочь мне, зарание спасибо всем кто даже просто прочел вопрос.

[image: наглядный пример дериктории]

Дальше мы идем в командную строку и прописываем следующие:
**javac -d classes -cp ../projectExample2/classes src/first/Example1.java**

И получаем такую штуку:
[image: Вид ошибки в консоли]

Классы Example1 и Example2:

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

Answer (score 0):

Принцип у вас правильный, видимо где-то опечатка.

У меня работает так (все в одной папке):

```
### Test0.java
package test0;
public class Test0 {}

### Test1.java
package test1;
import test0.Test0;
public class Test1 extends Test0 {}

### compile.sh
rm -r target0 target1
javac -d target0 Test0.java
javac -d target1 -cp target0 Test1.java

### запуск
docker run -v $(pwd):/app --workdir /app --rm -it openjdk sh compile.sh
```